# tabula error 'list' object has no attribute 'to_excel'

Tags: python, tabula

I tried to convert PDF file that contains the data table to excel file.
Here is my cord.

```
import tabula
  
# Read PDF File
df = tabula.read_pdf("files/Seniority List 2018 19.pdf", pages = 1)
  
# Convert into Excel File
df.to_excel('files/excel.xlsx')
```

but error occurred.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [5], in <cell line: 9>()
      6 df = tabula.read_pdf("files/Seniority List 2018 19.pdf", pages = 1)
      8 # # Convert into Excel File
----> 9 df.to_excel('files/excel.xlsx')

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_excel'
```

PDF is from here
https://www.docdroid.net/jTWmB15/seniority-list-2018-19-pdf

How can I use 'to_excel'??

I just mentioned the above settings in this question but still if more code is required then tell me I'll update my question with that information. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using `df = tabula.read_pdf('file.pdf', pages = '1')`

Use `df = tabula.read_pdf('file.pdf', pages = '1')[0]`

Answer (score 0):

```
df[0].to_excel('files/excel.xlsx')
```

tabula returns a list of possible table